# max heap on a binary tree

Tags: c, heap, binary-tree

I'm trying to make a function that will create a max heap tree.

The problem is
that I want my function to return the root of this tree, but I'm not sure how to do it.
I think that the lines here(1) and here(2) will make the function return the last node before insertion, and I can't think of a simple way of making it return the tree's root instead.

```
typedef struct node{
  int n;
  struct node* right;
  struct node* left;
}node; 

node * f(node* root, int v){
  node* p;
  if(!root){ //creating new node;
    p = malloc(sizeof(node));
    p->n = v;
    p->right = NULL;
    p->left = NULL;
    return p;
  }    

  if(v > root->n){ //if v is greater than the node, they'll be swapped.
    int aux = root->n;
    root->n = v;
    return f(root->right, aux); //here(1) 
  }

  //if v is smaller than the node, f will be called to the left node.
  if(v < root->n){ 
    int aux = root->n;
    return f(root->left, aux); //here(2)
  }

  return root;
}
```

Comment: It seems that since you don't swap pointers, just values, the root of the tree will never change. Do you need to keep track of it by returning it?

Comment: I don't believe your code will create a valid binary heap tree. Note that you are not updating the nodes `left` or `right` values anywhere, so you're not linking the nodes.

Comment: Also, if you add values in a crescent order, the tree will be unbalaced all the way to the right, so you better review your algorithm!

Comment: @jared_schmitz Yes I do.

Comment: @EricNielsen Makes sense, I'll do that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To make the function always return the root node, I would change the two lines with `//here` comments to:

```
f(root->right, aux); //here(1) 
return root;
```

and

```
f(root->left, aux); //here(2) 
return root;
```